# How do I scrub the sequencer playhead more than just 1 frame at a time

Tags: video-sequence-editor, shortcut

How do I scrub the sequencer playhead more than just 1 frame at a time (in 2.7 it was shift+up or down arrows)

I can't find anything for it in keymaps.

Comment: The ability to skip 10 frames forward and back with "shift+up" and "shift+down" is there in 2.81, i wonder which version you are mad at. Maybe updating could help you.

Comment: Sorry 'bout the wrong answer, added the proper solution

Answer (score 2):

You can revert back to Blender 2.7X keymap in the *Preferences*

[image]

**Edit: Sorry I didn't see the part about more than one frame at a time. My bad!**

If you wish to stick with the current keymap though, you can add another keybind for that.

Head back over to the *Preferences* tab, go to the *Keymap* option, and scroll down until you find the *Frames* dropdown menu.

At the bottom of that menu, click *Add New*. That will add a *none* shortcut, so open it up, and enter screen.frame_offset into the text entry on the left side. A *Delta* property will then be added, and change that to however frames you want to jump by. Then, just assign what keys you want to bind it to.

Repeat the process for the shortcut you want to jump forward/backward. Negative delta for moving back, positive for forwards.

[image]

Comment: Thanks and I'm sorry if I was rude it's just I did not expect blender to disable any hotkeys they weren't planning on replacing.